# Join 2D ranges horizontally in Googel Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've seen elsewhere that in **Google Sheets** the following will join two 3x3 ranges **vertically**:

```
={A1:C3;A11:C13}
```

And that the following will join two 3x3 ranges **horizontally**:

```
={A1:C3,A11:C13}
```

However the first works while the latter doesn't.
Where is my error? Is there a different way to join 2D ranges horizontally?

Comment: try replacing the comma with a backslash "\". It's probably related to your regional settings.

Comment: I'm sorry, the reason it didn't work for me was because of hidden columns :( SA won't let me delete the question because folks have answered it. I escalated to moderators so that this question will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

May be, due to your regional settings it is not working. You can use `VSTACK()` function to stack arrays vertically. Try-

```
=VSTACK(A1:C3,A11:C13)
```

To stack arrays horizontally you can use `HSTACK()`.

```
=HSTACK(A1:C3,A11:C13)
```

Comment: You may need to use semicolon `;` instead of comma `,` based on regional settings.

Comment: I'm sorry, the reason it didn't work for me was because of hidden columns :( SA won't let me delete the question because folks have answered it. I escalated to moderators so that this question will be deleted